# AreTransportControlsEnabled is disabled after entering full screen mode

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, win-universal-app, uwp-xaml

I am creating a CustomMediaTransportControls for `MediaPlayerElement`. In that, If I click FullScreen button to enter full screen then TransportControls is disabled after entering full-screen mode. I am not sure which line of code is causing it so I have attached entire code below.

1. [CustomMediaTransportControls.cs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rinrstt2xrpbfhf/CustomMediaTransportControls.cs?dl=0) - Derived class from `MediaTransportControls`
2. [MediaPlayerDictionary.xaml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jcadrad3165cxtb/MediaPlayerDictionary.xaml?dl=0) - `ResourceDictionary`
3. [VideosPage.xaml.cs](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vn5kqtu3evhqyo8/VideosPage.xaml.cs?dl=0) - C# part of the Page where `CustomMediaTransportControls` has been used
4. [VideosPage.xaml](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c5gssj7w3frthto/VideosPage.xaml?dl=0) - XAML part of the Page where `CustomMediaTransportControls` has been used

Comment: I have checked your code ,but I can not do the testing in my environment without some relative class such as `YouTubeQuality ` . Hence, is it possible to provide entire project.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT `YouTubeQuality` is from a NuGet package [MyToolKit.Extended](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MyToolkit.Extended).  GitHub Wiki - [YouTube](https://github.com/MyToolkit/MyToolkit/wiki/YouTube)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your issue. The problem is the `MediaPlayerElement.TransportControls` can't find `Page.Resources` 
 when the `MediaPlayerElement` is full screen.

You could  reference ["Create custom transport controls"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/controls-and-patterns/custom-transport-controls) to create a custom `TransportControls`, And put the control template in `generic.xaml` file or `App.xaml` file. So this template is the global ,and it can be accessed when `MediaPlayerElement` is full screen.

> The default style and template for each control is defined in the generic.xaml file. You can find the MediaTransportControls template in generic.xaml by searching for "MediaTransportControls".

I have uploaded the [code sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/CustomMediaControl.git) to github. Please check.

Comment: Then It's a bug. Anyway, your solution works. Thanks